# 'lessc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, Yii2 WAMP win8

Tags: less, yii2, wampserver

So i normally work on external servers, but decided to set up a local environment in the form of WAMPserver on my windows 8.1 computer.

From (git bash) console, i can run lessc without a problem, but when i install Yii2, and attempt to process .less it says it can't find the command.

```
AssetConverter command 'lessc "C:/wamp/www/basic/web/css/site.less" "C:/wamp/www/basic/web/css/site.css" --no-color --source-map' failed with exit code 1:
STDOUT:

STDERR:
'lessc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Now as far as i can tell, this should work. In fact, when i run that same command from console it works just fine. Am i missing a step here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Git Bash console is a unix-alike environment that runs on Windows. `lessc` is not a windows porcessor so as it say it does not exist in a vanilla windows command windows. I assume its a *nix proecessor you installed or they installed into GIT Bash.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I thought this might be it, but it does however also exist in my vanilla cmd.exe

Comment: Ahh interesting, thanks for the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing it by changing the command to reference the lessc.cmd directly

```
'assetManager'=>[
            'converter' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\AssetConverter',
                'commands' => [
                    'less' => ['css', 'c:\path\to\lessc.cmd {from} {to} --no-color'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Not to happy about the fix, because this means i will need to change my settings when i go 'live', but nothing else worked. I tried symlinking it into the yii directory, commands directory, etc.. but no good.

Comment: Still hoping someone can tell me why it didn't just work with the lessc command when it worked from cmd.exe, but i'll accept this as a workable solution if noone does

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it just now.

How should you do?

- Make sure you can run lessc in cmd windows.If you can't,install it with node.js [Install lessc with node.js](http://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2014/01/how-to-install-less-css-compiler-on-windows-7-for-phpstorm-7-0/)
- Make sure lessc path in system path.Mine is `C:\Users\l7861\AppData\Roaming\npm` or you can type `where lessc` in cmd windows to find it.
- Make sure you can see lessc path in `path_info()`.If you can't restart your apache server.
- Finally you don't need to add addassetManager in config never~~~~~

This below is a discovery process.

I just thought it is a bug on yii2 at first.So I debug it with Phpstrom.And I saw this line:`path\to\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\AssetConverter.php 91`

```
$command = Yii::getAlias($command);
    
    $command = strtr($command, [
        '{from}' => escapeshellarg("$basePath/$asset"),
        '{to}' => escapeshellarg("$basePath/$result"),
    ]);
    $descriptor = [
        1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
        2 => ['pipe', 'w'],
    ];
    $pipes = [];
    $proc = proc_open($command, $descriptor, $pipes, $basePath);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    foreach ($pipes as $pipe) {
        fclose($pipe);
    }
    $status = proc_close($proc);

    if ($status === 0) {
        Yii::trace("Converted $asset into $result:\nSTDOUT:\n$stdout\nSTDERR:\n$stderr", __METHOD__);
    } elseif (YII_DEBUG) {
        throw new Exception("AssetConverter command '$command' failed with exit code $status:\nSTDOUT:\n$stdout\nSTDERR:\n$stderr");
    } else {
        Yii::error("AssetConverter command '$command' failed with exit code $status:\nSTDOUT:\n$stdout\nSTDERR:\n$stderr", __METHOD__);
    }
    return $status === 0
}
```

Only if $status is not 0,then you got a error message.

And that usually means $command has something wrong.

When I ran to here, I could see it is `'lessc "path/to/frontend/web/less/main.less" "path/to/frontend/web/less/main.css" --no-color';`

And I ran it in cmd.Then css file was created by it.

I wrote a similar code below like that function

```
$command='lessc "path/to/frontend/web/less/main.less" "path/to/frontend/web/less/main.css" --no-color';
$basePath="path/to/frontend/web";
$descriptor = [
    1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
    2 => ['pipe', 'w'],
];
$pipes = [];

$process = proc_open($command, $descriptor, $pipes /* $cwd, $env */ );
print_r($pipes);

$stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
echo mb_convert_encoding($stdout, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8,GBK,GB2312,BIG5' );
$stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
echo mb_convert_encoding($stderr, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8,GBK,GB2312,BIG5' );
if (is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[1], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
```

And ran it in browser.Then I got a error "lessc is not recognized as an internal or external command".

So I chang config file config/main.php,

```
    return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'assetManager' => [
            'converter' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\AssetConverter',
                'commands' => [
                    'less' => ['css', 'lessc {from} {to} --no-color'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'name' => 'FavorTGD',
];
```

I got a same a same message.So I check out `php_info()`,there no lessc program in path.there there.That all you need is just restart your apache.

And delete assetManager in main.php